# Convert an array of functions into nested function calls

Tags: javascript

I am given an array of functions of length N, where every function has an asynchronous call and accepts a callback argument. The callback of function[x] is function[x+1], and function[N-1] has no callback. Here's an example of what I might be given:

```
function func1(callback){
  $.ajax({
    //Ajax settings
  }).done(function(){
    console.log('foo1');
    if(callback) callback();
  });
}

function func2(callback){
  $.ajax({
    //Ajax settings
  }).done(function(){
    console.log('foo2');
    if(callback) callback();
  });
}

function func3(callback){
  $.ajax({
    //Ajax settings
  }).done(function(){
    console.log('foo3');
    if(callback) callback();
  });
}

var funcs = [func1, func2, func3];
```

Am I able to build the following nested calls for the example without just building a string and calling *eval()*:

```
func1(function(){
  func2(function(){
    func3()
  })
})

/* 
  Output:
  foo1
  foo2
  foo3
*/
```

Edit: They have to be nested because I need them to run synchronously. For-loops or *foreach()* create race conditions.

Comment: It's an array, so... forEach?  `funcs.forEach(f => f());`

Comment: @LukStorms That would create N non-nested calls. The functions themselves are asynchronous, but I need to call the functions in a way that's synchronous to eliminate race conditions.

Comment: Ah ok, connecting the async's.  That's a bit more tricky. You might want to make that goal clear in your question.

Comment: Use `Promise.all`, it is not the straight answer to your question, but it should fulfill your use case better

Comment: @quirimmo I have to support IE. I didn't say that in the question because I figured supporting IE would be too specific to my use case and didn't want to rule out modern JS APIs, so +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a new function, which chains all the functions in the array:

```
funcx = funcs.reduceRight((f2, f1) => x => f1(f2(x)));
```

Then call this function:

```
funcx();
```

Of course, you could do it also in on step, but it might be a bit confusing:

```
funcs.reduceRight((f2, f1) => x => f1(f2(x)))();
```

If you want to be prepared for an empty array of functions, you can do it like this:

```
funcs.reduceRight((f2, f1) => x => f1(f2(x)), x => 0)();
```

Comment: He wants output to be 'output1', then 'output2', then 'output3'.  So I think you've got to switch your nesting order.  Otherwise, I've didn't know about `reduceRight`, so thanks for that.

Comment: @pwilcox, yes, thanks for the hint. I had it first with ```reduceRight```, but then I erreanously changed it to ```reduce```. I have reversed my change now.

Comment: This is awesome! Accepted answer because it has the best cross browser compatibility (works in IE9+) and accomplishes exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Creating Promise can make the solution easy. Please follow the sample.

```
const delay =  (v) => {
  return new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(x => r(v), 10000 * Math.random())
  })
}
async function  dummyAjax() {
  const data = await delay(Math.random() * 10)
  return data
}
async function  func1() {
  return dummyAjax()
}
async function  func2() {
  return dummyAjax()
}
async function  func3() {
  return dummyAjax()
}
console.time("PROMISE: TOTAL_TIME")
Promise.all([func1(), func2(), func3()])
    .then((responses) => {
        responses.forEach(console.log)
        console.timeEnd("PROMISE: TOTAL_TIME")
    })
```

I have created a series of the solution on all types of async ways to addressing the issue. Please check my gist page.

https://gist.github.com/deepakshrma/1a899bf49ccb77d3b5be771907b32e4c

Answer (score 1):

If all of your functions returned the promise, then your solution is easy. First, add a `return` statement to each of your functions:

```
function func1(callback){
  return $.ajax(...);
}
```

Then, you could just do this:

```
func1()
.then(func2)
.then(func3)
.then(result => console.log('DONE!', result))
.catch(err => console.log('OH NO!', err));
```

If you want to keep the array, then you can do this:

```
var funcs = [func1, func2, func3];
funcs.reduce((promise, func, i) => {
  if(i === 0) return promise();
  return promise.then(func);
})
.then(result => console.log('DONE!', result))
.catch(err => console.log('OH NO!', err));
```